# Confidence interval for the product of two parameters

Tags: confidence-interval

Let us assume we have two parameters, $p_1$ and $p_2$. We also have two maximum likelihood estimators $\hat{p}_1$ and $\hat{p}_2$ and two confidence intervals for these parameters. Is there a way to build a confidence interval for $p_1p_2?$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [Delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) to calculate the standard error of $\hat{p}_{1}\hat{p}_{2}$. The delta method states that an approximation of the variance of a function $g(t)$ is given by:
$$
\mathrm{Var}(g(t))\approx \sum_{i=1}^{k}g'_{i}(\theta)^{2}\,\mathrm{Var}(t_{i})+2\sum_{i>j}g'_{i}(\theta)g'_{j}(\theta)\,\mathrm{Cov}(t_{i},t_{j}).
$$
The approximation of the expectation of $g(t)$ on the other hand is given by:
$$
\mathrm{\mathbf{E}}(g(t))\approx g(\theta)
$$
So the expectation is simply the function. Your function $g(t)$ is: $g(p_{1}, p_{2})=p_{1}p_{2}$. The expectation of  $g(p_{1}, p_{2})=p_{1}p_{2}$ would simply be: $p_{1}p_{2}$. For the variance, we need the partial derivatives of $g(p_{1}, p_{2})$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{1}}g(p_{1}p_{2}) & = p_{2} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{2}}g(p_{1}p_{2}) &= p_{1} \\
\end{align}
$$

Using the function for the variance above, we get:

$$
\mathrm{Var}(\hat{p}_{1}\hat{p}_{2})=\hat{p}_{2}^{2}\,\mathrm{Var}(\hat{p}_{1}) + \hat{p}_{1}^{2}\,\mathrm{Var}(\hat{p}_{2})+2\cdot \hat{p}_{1}\hat{p}_{2}\,\mathrm{Cov}(\hat{p}_{1},\hat{p}_{2}).
$$
The standard error would then simply be the square root of the above expression. Once you've got the standard error, it is straight-forward to calculate a $95\%$ confidence interval for $\hat{p}_{1}\hat{p}_{2}$: $\hat{p}_{1}\hat{p}_{2}\pm 1.96\cdot \widehat{\mathrm{SE}}(\hat{p}_{1}\hat{p}_{2})$

To calculate the standard error of $\hat{p}_{1}\hat{p}_{2}$, you need the variance of $\hat{p}_{1}$ and $\hat{p}_{2}$ which you usually can get by the [**variance-covariance matrix** $\Sigma$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) which would be a $2\times 2$-matrix in your case because you have two estimates. The diagonal elements in the variance-covariance matrix are the variances of $\hat{p}_{1}$ and $\hat{p}_{2}$ while the off-diagonal elements are the covariance of $\hat{p}_{1}$ and $\hat{p}_{2}$ (the matrix is symmetric). As @gung mentions in the comments, the variance-covariance matrix can be extracted by most statistical software packages. Sometimes, estimation algorithms provide the [Hessian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) (I won't go into details about that here), and the variance-covariance matrix can be estimated by the **inverse of the negative Hessian** (but only if you maximized the log-likelihood!; see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27033/in-r-given-an-output-from-optim-with-a-hessian-matrix-how-to-calculate-paramet)). Again, consult the documentation of your statistical software and/or the web on how to extract the Hessian and on how to calculate the inverse of a matrix.

Alternatively, you can get the variances of $\hat{p}_{1}$ and $\hat{p}_{2}$ from the confidence intervals in the following way (this is valid for a $95\%$-CI): $\mathrm{SE}(\hat{p}_{1})=(\text{upper limit} - \text{lower limit})/3.92$. For an $100(1-\alpha)\%$-CI, the estimated standard error is: $\mathrm{SE}(\hat{p}_{1})=(\text{upper limit} - \text{lower limit})/(2\cdot z_{1-\alpha/2})$, where $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ is the $(1-\alpha/2)$ quantile of the standard normal distribution (for $\alpha=0.05$, $z_{0.975}\approx 1.96$). Then, $\mathrm{Var}(\hat{p}_{1}) = \mathrm{SE}(\hat{p}_{1})^{2}$. The same is true for the variance of $\hat{p}_{2}$. We need the covariance of $\hat{p}_{1}$ and $\hat{p}_{2},$ too (see paragraph above). If $\hat{p}_{1}$ and $\hat{p}_{2}$ are independent, the covariance is zero and we can drop the term.

[This paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2281697?uid=3737760&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21102417127101) might provide additional information.

Comment: +1. The variances of the parameters & their covariance can be found by examining the variance-covariance matrix of $\boldsymbol\beta$, which most statistical software can provide. Eg, in R, it's [?vcov](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/vcov.html); & in SAS, `covb` is added [as an option to the model statement in PROC REG](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_sect033.htm).

Comment: @gung On a point of pedantry it might be worth pointing out (because I know it confuses some people) that it's really the variance-covariance matrix of $\hat \beta$ rather than $\beta$ (and in fact it isn't even really that, because the standard deviation has to be estimated from the sample, so it's really the *estimated* variance-covariance matrix..)

Comment: @Silverfish, duly chastised. Next time I'll say "the estimated variance-covariance matrix of $\boldsymbol{\hat\beta}$".

Comment: You could try to construct a profile likelihood function! and construct the confidence interval from that.

Comment: Isn’t $var(p_1)=0$ since it’s a parameter?

Comment: @user0 Yes, the (unknown) parameter, i.e. the true population value of $p_1$ has zero variance since it's assumed to be fixed. But the question seeks a confidence interval for the *estimates* of these parameters, and these estimates have corresponding variances.

Comment: Then $var(p_1p_2)$ above, should the ps have hats?

Comment: @user0 Ah yes, of course. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, if we expect the product of p1_hat and p2_hat to be significantly non-normal, we wouldn't be able to use the standard normal-based CI for it, would we? In that case just knowing the variance wouldn't be enough, I think. Is a Bayesian approach [like this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/493716/accounting-for-multiple-layers-of-uncertainty-in-a-model) a better option in that scenario?

Comment: The delta method is justified asymptotically by the CLT, yes. So for small samples or proportions near the boundary I would be suspicious. Another possibility to calculate confidence intervals is the bootstrap or some Bayesian approach.

Answer (score 3):

I found a different equation for calculation of variance of product.

> If x and y are independently distributed, the variance of the product
>   is relatively straightforward: 
>   V(x*y)= V(y)*E(x)^2  + V(x)*E(y)^2 + V(x)*V(y)
>   These results also generalize to cases
>   involving three or more variables (Goodman 1960).
>   Source: [Regulating Pesticides (1980), appendix F](http://www.nap.edu/read/54/chapter/14)

Coolserdash: The last component V(x)*V(y) is missing in your equation. Is the referenced book (Regulating Pesticides) wrong?

Also, both equations might not be perfect. "*... we show that the distribution of the product of three independent normal variables is not normal*." ([source](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cem.1180050317/abstract)). I would expect some **positive skew** even in the product of two normally distributed variables.

Answer (score 0):

1. The length of the CI / 2 / 1.96 = se, i.e. the standard error of A or B
2. se^2 = var, i.e. the variance of the estimate A or B
3. Use the estimated A or B as the means of A or B, i.e. E(A) or E(B)
4. Follow this page http://falkenblog.blogspot.se/2008/07/formula-for-varxy.html to get var(A*B), i.e. var(C)
5. Square-root of var(C) is the se of C
6. (C - 1.96*se(C), C + 1.96*se(C)) is the 95% CI of C

Note that if your A and B are correlated, you need to consider their covariance as well.