# Is there a notion of the product of confidence bands?

Tags: confidence-interval

Given two confidence bands, it seems natural to consider the confidence band of the product of these two distributions. Does this have a name? Are there any reference that might be helpful regarding this notion?

Edit: Assume that the errors of the first, say, regression curve are not correlated with the errors of the second.

Comment: Threads about the [delta method](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=delta+method) are likely to provide appropriate solutions.

Comment: You might need to a bit more specific, @Gregorian Funk. Did you mean, say, the confidence interval of a variable that is the product of two variables whose confidence intervals are known?

Comment: Yes, I am asking for a new confidence band of the product of the two curves. Assume that each curve is derived from some simple regression, and it is assumed that the errors are uncorrelated.

Comment: As @whuber said, the delta method might be an answer. This might also interest you: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62916/confidence-interval-for-the-product-of-two-parameters