# Confidence interval for vertex of quadratic model, transforming parameters estimated by MLE

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, inverse-prediction

If I have a model $y=ax^2+bx+c+\epsilon$, and I use [maximum likelihood estimation](http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/5931/mle/mle.pdf) (in R, with `nlm` function) to estimate $(a,b,c)$ with a Hessian matrix $H$ as a results, can I use this to calculate the (95%) C.I. for the $x$-coordinate of the vertex (i.e. turning point; the minimum or maximum depending on the sign of $a$), $\mu=-\frac{b}{2a}$?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62916/confidence-interval-for-the-product-of-two-parameters). You should be able to follow the answer there.

Comment: @GuðmundurEinarsson Good spot. Although the mathematical details are very similar, and someone competent with calculus and a little theory ought to be able to deduce the answer to this problem from the proposed duplicate, I don't think it would hurt to let this question stand as an example for quotients and the proposed duplicate for products. This particular use case is not an obscure or artificial one (it's no mere homework question), and is likely to be of interest to future readers, who would presumably prefer a fully worked solution, rather than working it out from first principles.

Comment: @Silverfish fair point! I will potentially write an answer later tonight or tomorrow. OP could also try to write an answer from this and we can guide him/her if he/she gets stuck.

Comment: I've edited to include a few tags. I've also changed "center" to "vertex" or "turning point" as [this seems to be the more usual term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola) and should be more searchable for future readers. Feel free to revert this change if there was some specific reason you wanted to call it the "center". (Personally I might be a little wary of assigning the symbol $\mu$ to it, but perhaps you are working in an application where this is standard notation, so I have left it.)

Comment: @Silverfish I have added an answer, I found some other stuff that I added and might be relevant for others.

Comment: Thank you guys for your detailed answer! I will also read the related post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Small Disclaimer

You do not need the nlm package to solve your problem. You have a linear model, it is still linear although your variables are non-linear.

### Small Intro

My answer is based on the comment I made to your question. I am going to use the [Delta method](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cme308/OldWebsite/notes/TaylorAppDeltaMethod.pdf) to construct a confidence interval for you.

The Delta method is based on an approximation of the variance of your new parameter $\mu$. So **this is an approximation**, and we will verify (*somewhat*) how good it is with a simulation example.

[This is in fact not an easy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Gaussian_ratio_distribution). The parameters in a linear model (*your model is linear in the parameters, thus linear*) follow a multivariate normal distribution and they are **not** independent. Thus the exact distribution is not easy to derive, and I do not have an idea of how to find it now. So let the approximation do.

### Let's solve this

I will call your *new* parameter $\mu:= g(a,b)$.

The function you provide is $g(a,b)=-\frac{b}{2a}$. It is worth mentioning that a function of MLEs is an MLE, so the expected value is
$$
\text{E}[-\frac{B}{2A}]=-\frac{b}{2a}
$$
Where $A$ and $B$ are the RVs corresponding to the estimators for $a$ and $b$ (*This may be some abuse of notation*). Now the confidence interval is symmetric, so the center will be the expected values.

On the top of page 6 in the document in Delta method link, your problem is solved, i.e. when the function $g$ is the quotient of two RVs. The only difference is that you scale the quotient by $\frac{-1}{2}$. So the variance of $g(A,B)$ is:
$$
\begin{align}
    \text{Var}[g(A,B)] &= \text{Var}[-\frac{B}{2A}]\\
    &= \frac{1}{4}\text{Var}[\frac{B}{A}]\\
    &\approx \frac{1}{4} (\frac{b}{a})^2(\frac{\text{Var}[B]}{b^2}
    + \frac{\text{Var}[A]}{a^2}
    - 2\frac{\text{Cov}[A,B]}{ab})
\end{align}
$$
You should have everything you need to calculate this, just plug in the point estimates of $a$ and $b$ and find the corresponding variances and covariances in the covariance matrix of the parameters.

Your 95% confidence interval (*I picked $\alpha$ as 5% for the sake of demonstration*) thus becomes 
$$
-\frac{\hat{b}}{2\hat{a}}\pm 1.96\cdot\sqrt{\text{Var}[-\frac{\hat{b}}{2\hat{a}}]}
$$

### Small Simulation Study

Now let's check how good this estimator really is. This is quite a lot of code, try it out to get a feel for what is happening:

```
# Start by generating data

a <- 1.5
b <- 2
c <- 3
trueVal <- -0.5*b/a

x <- seq(-5,5,length=100)
y <- a*x^2 + b*x+c

plot(x, y, main = "Some quadratic function")

# Let's remove some of the x's
x <- x[-sample(1:100,80)]
x2 <- x^2
y <- a*x2 + b*x+c

plot(x, y, main = "Removed points")

# Add some error to this
yErr <- y + rnorm(20, mean=0, sd=5)
plot(x, yErr, main = "With error")

# Now let's estimate the parameters
fm <- lm(yErr~x2+x)
params <- coef(fm)

# Look at parameters (They are very close to our defined a,b and c)
summary(fm)

# We can find the covariance matrix by looking at
varMat <- vcov(fm)

# So we can get an estimate for the 95% confidence interval as:
leftVal <- -0.5*params[3]/params[2]-
  1.96*sqrt(0.25*(params[3]/params[2])^2*
    (varMat[3,3]/params[3]^2 +
     varMat[2,2]/params[2]^2 -
     2*varMat[2,3]/(params[2]*params[3]) ))

rightVal <- -0.5*params[3]/params[2]+
  1.96*sqrt(0.25*(params[3]/params[2])^2*
    (varMat[3,3]/params[3]^2 +
     varMat[2,2]/params[2]^2 -
     2*varMat[2,3]/(params[2]*params[3]) ))

# Let's encapsulate this in a function
confQuot <- function(params,varMat){
  leftVal <- -0.5*params[3]/params[2]-
    1.96*sqrt(0.25*(params[3]/params[2])^2*
      (varMat[3,3]/params[3]^2 +
       varMat[2,2]/params[2]^2 -
       2*varMat[2,3]/(params[2]*params[3]) ))
  rightVal <- -0.5*params[3]/params[2]+
    1.96*sqrt(0.25*(params[3]/params[2])^2*
      (varMat[3,3]/params[3]^2 +
       varMat[2,2]/params[2]^2 -
       2*varMat[2,3]/(params[2]*params[3]) ))
  return(c(leftVal,rightVal))
}

# Now let's simulate this and see how often the 
# true value falls in this interval
numSamps <- 10000
counter <- 0
for(i in 1:numSamps){
  yErr <- y + rnorm(20, mean=0, sd=5)
  fm <- lm(yErr~x2+x)
  params <- coef(fm)
  varMat <- vcov(fm)
  confs <- confQuot(params,varMat)
  if(trueVal>confs[1] & trueVal<confs[2]){
    counter <- counter + 1
  }
}

# Simulations give that the true value falls in 
# the interval this proportion of the simulations
(counter/numSamps)
```

I get the following value from my runs:

```
> (counter/numSamps)
[1] 0.9352
```

So it is not exactly 95% but very close indeed. If you are reporting this for something I would at least perform some kind of a simulation like this to get a feel for the true $\alpha$ in your interval. You would also want to try the simulation with different errors and different number of points.

Hope this helped.