# Accounting for multiple layers of uncertainty in a model

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, prediction-interval, uncertainty

Let's say I have data on 10 stores that sell widgets, each of which received `num_orders` number of orders in a certain timeframe, and sold a total of `total_qty` widgets in that timeframe. In other words, for store *i*, the average quantity per order is `total_qty_i/num_orders_i`.

**My goal is to use this data produce a prediction interval for the `total_qty` variable that accounts for the fact that there are two layers of uncertainty:**

1. We don't know how many orders a store will get - there is a distribution of `num_orders`
2. Even once we know how many orders the store gets, there is uncertainty because we don't know what the quantity for each order will be.

**What's the best way to do this?**

Let's say the data look like this (in reality, of course, I don't know the distributions that gave rise to the data)

```
num_stores <- 10

df <- 
    tibble(store_id = 1:num_stores, 
           num_orders = rpois(num_stores, 50), 
           total_qty  = rpois(num_stores, 100))
```

My idea is to use a Bayesian approach:

1. Write down a generative probability model
2. Fit the model to the data and get samples of parameters from the posterior distribution
3. Simulate a large number of data points with the samples from the posterior, and then take the 5th and 95th quantiles of that set of simulated datapoints.

Is this a sensible approach?

As an example, this is the probability model I might start with:

```
total_qty ~ dpois(lambda_qty*orders)  # sum of Poissons is Poisson
orders ~ dpois(lambda_orders) 
lambda_qty ~ dnorm(30, 2)  # prior for avg qty ordered 
lambda_orders ~ dexp(1)    # prior for avg num orders
```

I'm pretty new to Bayesian analysis, so would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, *"simulating a large number of data points with the samples from the posterior and taking the 5th and 95th quantiles of that simulated dataset"* is a totally sensible approach, and the it's known as sampling from the **predictive posterior distribution**.

Now, the Poisson distribution is not the best choice for `total_qty`, since `total_qty` is a continuous random variable, not a discrete one. I think we can improve this model as follows. Let's start with these priors:

```
lambda_orders ~ dexp(1) # prior for avg num orders
lambda_qty ~ dnorm(30, 10)  # prior for avg qty ordered 
sigma_qty ~ dexp(1) # prior for st. dev. qty ordered
```

[I increased the prior variance of `lambda_qty`, because it is the *prior distribution*, not the *predictive distribution*, so it's usually better to keep wider distributions. But if you have prior knowledge that `lambda_qty` is between 26 and 34 with high probability, you should keep that prior just the way you wrote it.]

Then, we can keep a Poisson distribution for `orders`, since it represents a count. [If there's overdispersion one would prefer a negative binomial, but let's ignore it for now.]

```
orders ~ dpois(lambda_orders)
```

Finally, we can assume the value for each order follows a normal distribution, with mean `lambda_qty` and standard deviation `sigma_qty`. Adding a number `orders` of normal RVs with that distribution gives us a new variable with mean `orders*lambda_qty` and standard deviation `orders*sigma_qty`. Thus, we write:

```
total_qty ~ dnorm(orders*lambda_qty, orders*sigma_qty)
```

That concludes our Bayesian model! Hope it was helpful

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful! Just one point of clarification: I was actually thinking of `total_qty` as a discrete variable - e.g. one order could be for 2 widgets, or 3 widgets, but not 2.5. But I can see that the way I named it might suggest dollar amounts instead, which would be continuous. In any case, your response is very valuable in validating the general idea I had.