# Maximum likelihood optimization error in R

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, optimization

**Edit: A link to the data and nlm() tracing information has been added, and the code has been changed in accordance with suggestions from the comments**

Download the data from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnlj9rdsh320qh7/Data.zip). (Dropbox link).

Download the nlm() tracing information from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6lcn79qx3lo9wpk/iteration_info.txt). (Dropbox link)

I am working on a problem to find the maximum likelihood estimators $\left( \hat\sigma_n^2,\hat l,\hat\sigma_f^2 \right)$ for some data. The log likelihood is

$$\log \mathcal{L} \left( \sigma_n^2,l,\sigma_f^2 \right)=  -\frac{1}{2} y^T \left(\mathbf{K}+\sigma_n^2\mathbf{I} \right)^{-1}y - \frac{1}{2} \log \left| \mathbf{K}+\sigma_n^2\mathbf{I} \right| - \frac{n}{2} \log2\pi$$

$y$ is a $n \times 1$ vector obtained from my data (response variables). $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix. $\mathbf{K}$ is a  $n\times n$ matrix depending on $\sigma_f^2$ and $l$; its matrix elements are:

$$K_{pq} = \sigma_f^2 \exp\left( - \frac{1}{2l^2} \left| x_p -x_q \right|^2 \right)$$

$x_i$ are $3\times1$ vectors (independent variables).

I tried to find the maximum likelihood estimators in R by minimizing the negative log likelihood. The functions I tried using were *nlm* and *optim*. Both gave the same error - NA/Inf were produced. How do I proceed to calculate the estimators? I would prefer more accessible answers. (I am only a beginner)

I will write my code below for reference. The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ in the code (and download) is given by:

$$A_{pq} = \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2} \left| x_p -x_q \right|^2 \right) $$

```
load("A.Rdata") # Contains matrix A to help calculate K (in the formula above).
                # A is the exponential part of the formula. (but without the 'l squared' part) 
load("y.Rdata") # Contains the response variable y

num_unique <- 786

Calculate_K_plus <- function(vect){
  sn2 <- vect[1]*vect[1]
  exponent <- 1/(vect[2]*vect[2])
  sf2 <- vect[3]*vect[3]
  B <- A^exponent
  B <- sf2 * B
  B <- B + sn2*diag(num_unique)
  return(B)}

minus_log_likelihood <- function(vect){
 K_plus <- Calculate_K_plus(vect)
 K_plus_inv <- solve(K_plus)
 out = 0.5 * ( t(y) %*% K_plus_inv %*% y) + 0.5 * log(det(K_plus)) + (num_unique/2)*log(2*pi)
 return(out)}

nlm(minus_log_likelihood,c(1,1,1))
```

Comment: I tried to run the code but it gave an error: we need the value of `num_unique`.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Sorry about that, I will edit it in. But do note that this is meant to be a "reproducible example"; I can't give the whole data set here as it is very large.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. But this is still not a reproducible example as we can't reproduce your error. `y` and `X` are both filled with `NA`s (missings). Maybe you could just add a very small subset of your data set?

Comment: I think I've spotted one error: in the function for the negative log-likelihood, you calculate the determinant of the *inverse* of $\mathbf{K}$. In your log-likelihood function, the determinant of $\mathbf{K}$ should be calculated. Try saving the inverse of $\mathbf{K}$ first.

Comment: @COOLSerdash I changed the code. But the same error comes up...it seems at some point in the algorithm the matrix becomes singular. Also if I give you a subset of the code, do you think it be helpful for the whole data set?

Comment: If we assume that your likelihood function is correct, then it's either a mistake in the code or some numerical problem with `optim` or `nlm`. Have you tried setting different starting values? Or try using the option `print.level=2` for `nlm` to trace the optimization calculation. Maybe this will give you a hint where things go wrong.

Comment: Some comments: the code is wrong. Also, avoid ever using lowcase l as a vector name because lines like this: `1 / (l * l)` are unreadable in monospace. It also helps to use the `traceback()` function to debug your errors. This points to your `Calculate_K_plus` function. Also, are you aware you have `NAs` in your matrices? `A` and `B` have dim 3x3 whereas diag(num_unique) is 1000x1000.

Comment: I'm not 100% up to speed with reading R. However, it looks like you've forgotten to square sn2 and sf2 the way you did with l. If they then take negative values (which optim will allow) then that could mess things up quite a bit.

Comment: @AdamO Sorry about that, I was just trying to keep consistent with the notation. Also `A` is a 1000x1000 matrix, you might have missed the `t(X)` in the command to calculate `A`. I did think `Calculate_K_plus` was the problem...my thoughts were that it due to some problem with the data perhaps. Could there be an alternate way to approach the problem?

Comment: @COOLSerdash I will try you suggestion tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: @Pat Thanks for the suggestion, but `vect` passes the square of the two sigmas. But I will try and alter the code to square the sigmas separately tomorrow.

Comment: @Comp_Warrior You need to run your code to verify these things. `as.matrix(dist(t(X)))` is a 3x3 matrix indeed.

Comment: @AdamO You are right, I will remove the transpose. Thanks.

Comment: Now tell us `X` has no finite values (all missing). Why are you calculating a distance matrix for it? It makes no sense.

Comment: @AdamO I have added a link to download data for the matrix `A` and vector `y` (from a dropbox link). I calculated the distance matrix (`A`) to speed up the program when eventually calculating `K`. I started the program from different points in the parameter space, and the same problem persists. Can you have a look at the program on your machine?

Comment: @COOLSerdash I got the tracing information...it seems the first component of the gradient goes to infinity. As far as I can see, I have followed the formulas given. Do you know what is going on?

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thanks for your input, the answers seem reasonable. Would you say that this problem was due to the algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This got too long for a comment. The problem with your function is that the determinant of `K_plus` was getting infinite or zero very quickly. I tweaked your function to calculate the log-determinant directly. I then used `optim` with different methods as well as `nlm` to search for the maximum likelihood estimates. The algorithms converged without problems. I also included the code to calculate the standard errors and confidence intervals [based on the Hessian](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27033/in-r-given-an-output-from-optim-with-a-hessian-matrix-how-to-calculate-paramet). All algorithms give very similar estimates.

The estimates are: $\widehat{\sigma}_{n}=5.30,\hat{l}=5.12,\widehat{\sigma}_{f}=45.01$.

The code is:

```
load("A.Rdata")
load("y.Rdata")

num_unique <- 786

Calculate_K_plus <- function(vect){
  sn2 <- (vect[1]*vect[1])
  exponent <- 1/(vect[2]*vect[2])
  sf2 <- vect[3]*vect[3]
  B <- A^exponent
  B <- sf2 * B
  B <- B + sn2*diag(num_unique)
  B
}

minus_log_likelihood <- function(vect){
  K_plus <- Calculate_K_plus(vect)
  K_plus_inv <- solve(K_plus)
  z <- determinant(K_plus, logarithm=TRUE)  
  K_plus_log_det <- as.numeric((z$sign*z$modulus)) # log-determinant of K_plus
  out <- 0.5 * ( t(y) %*% K_plus_inv %*% y ) + 0.5 * K_plus_log_det + (num_unique/2)*log(2*pi)
  out
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "Nelder-Mead" algorithm
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

res.optim <- optim(par=c(5.3, 5.1, 44.9), fn=minus_log_likelihood, hessian=TRUE, control=list(trace=TRUE, maxit=1000))

res.optim$par    
[1]  5.302362  5.123045 45.011507

fisher_info<- solve(res.optim$hessian)
prop_sigma<-sqrt(diag(fisher_info))
upper<-res.optim$par+1.96*prop_sigma
lower<-res.optim$par-1.96*prop_sigma
interval<-data.frame(value=res.optim$par, lower=lower, upper=upper)
interval

      value     lower     upper
1  5.302362  5.032848  5.571877
2  5.123045  3.442932  6.803157
3 45.011507 17.952756 72.070257

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "L-BFGS-B" algorithm
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

res.optim2 <- optim(par=c(5.3, 5.1, 44.9), fn=minus_log_likelihood, method=c("L-BFGS-B"), hessian=TRUE, control=list(trace=3, maxit=1000))

res.optim2    
[1]  5.301418  5.114984 44.901863

fisher_info<- solve(res.optim2$hessian)
prop_sigma<-sqrt(diag(fisher_info))
upper<-res.optim2$par+1.96*prop_sigma
lower<-res.optim2$par-1.96*prop_sigma
interval2<-data.frame(value=res.optim2$par, lower=lower, upper=upper)
interval2

      value     lower     upper
1  5.301418  5.031988  5.570848
2  5.114984  3.437925  6.792043
3 44.901863 17.982520 71.821206

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# With "nlminb"
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

res.nlm <- nlminb(objective=minus_log_likelihood, start=c(5.3, 5.1, 44.9), control=list(iter.max=200, trace=1))

res.nlm$par
[1]  5.301542  5.123718 45.072189

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# With "nlm"
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

res.nlm2 <- nlm(f=minus_log_likelihood, p=c(5.3, 5.1, 44.9), print.level=2)

res.nlm2$estimate
[1]  5.301534  5.123776 45.072711
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. But this answer is different from the `nlm` function; which one do you think is more "trust worthy"?

Comment: I've updated my answer and included the results from `nlm`, they are the same. I would personally trust these results.